# VisualState AdaptiveTrigger not working with RelativePanel

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have the following xaml

```
 <Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Name="MainView">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0">                
            <Slider Width="350" Name="ZoomSlider"  Margin="10" Minimum="30" Maximum="200"   Value="100" SnapsTo="Ticks" TickFrequency="10"
                    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" />

            <Button Width="100" Name="btn_prev" Margin="10" Click="btn_prev_Click" RelativePanel.LeftOf="ZoomSlider">Previous</Button>
            <Button Width="100" Name="btn_next" Margin="10" Click="btn_next_Click" RelativePanel.RightOf="ZoomSlider">Next</Button>
            <Button Width="100" Foreground="White" Background="DarkBlue" Name="btn_Extraspage"  Content="Extra page" RelativePanel.RightOf="btn_next" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="btn_next" Click="btn_Extraspage_Click"/>               
        </RelativePanel>
        <WebView  Name="book_view" LoadCompleted="book_view_LoadCompleted"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 5"></WebView>
        <!-- Responsive VisualStates -->
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
                    <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=548 and <720 effective pixels -->
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="btn_prev.(RelativePanel.LeftOf)" Value="ZoomSlider" />

                        <Setter Target="btn_next.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="ZoomSlider" />

                        <Setter Target="btn_Extraspage.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="btn_next" />
                        <Setter Target="btn_Extraspage.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="btn_next" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowStateReadView">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--RelativePanel.Below="ZoomSlider" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="ZoomSlider"-->
                        <Setter Target="btn_prev.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="ZoomSlider" />
                        <Setter Target="btn_prev.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith)" Value="ZoomSlider" />

                        <!--RelativePanel.LeftOf="btn_Extraspage" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="btn_prev"-->
                        <Setter Target="btn_next.(RelativePanel.LeftOf)" Value="btn_Extraspage" />
                        <Setter Target="btn_next.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="btn_prev" />


                        <!--RelativePanel.Below="ZoomSlider" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="ZoomSlider" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="btn_prev"-->
                        <Setter Target="btn_Extraspage.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="ZoomSlider" />
                        <Setter Target="btn_Extraspage.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWith)" Value="ZoomSlider" />
                        <Setter Target="btn_Extraspage.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="btn_prev" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
```

My expectation is to place Previous button and next button to left and right of slider on wide view

And to place Previous and next button below slider to left and right on narrow view

The XAML parsed without error , but rendering effect is not as expected. The NarrowStateReadview trigger looks not firing for me

Answer (score 2):

Until it changes, the attached property VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups must appear in the first UIElement in your case the first Grid in order to work.

```
<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
                <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=548 and <720 effective pixels -->
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
```

It doesn't mind it don't apply to the first Grid it has to go there.

And if you want more information about the VisualStates I made an article about that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/896974/Advanced-View-States-for-Windows-apps